# My program is stuck in do,,while loop in c

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, do-while

I have a problem solving this issue:
I have to receive  numbers as an input and the first number has to be 0(if the number is 0 close the loop) but the compiler let me put just one number as an input and when I press enter it stucks
here is my code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 int main(){
  int num=0, max=0, first=0, a=0, b=0;

  do{

      b = num /10;
      if(b==0)

        scanf("%d", &num);


      else{
        a = num%10;
        if (max < a){
          max = a;
          first = num;
          a=b;
        }
    }

  }
  while(num > 0);

  printf("%d\n%d", max, first);




}
```

Comment: I think it's time for you to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: i read it wrong! too fast to post, then too quick to delete! it's back now!

Answer (score 4):

`num` and `b` are not set in the loop's `else`-branch other than `b` to be `num/10`. So it will just run the `else`-branch forever

Comment: In the future, please edit your current answer instead, and then undelete it.

Comment: Assuming it *gets* into the `else` branch.

Comment: will do, but the `undelete` option was not available to me at the time. Or at least not visible. I imagine if i would have refreshed the page it would have shown up.